# RDLC - Creating a DataSet with DataTable in Code #

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, rdlc

I would like to know if i can create Dataset into my report and without adding the columns in the .xsd Dataset
I was trying to make it in the code it was giving me an exception that the report Viewer is Invalid.

```
***The definition of the report 'reportViewer1' is invalid***
```

Comment: AFAIK rdlc reports require you to define your dataset on the report so that you can design the report with the appropriate columns involved. You can then pass your populated dataset onto an rdlc report through code if you want to fetch the data outside of the report.

Comment: @jegtugado can u give me an example please?

Comment: i need to bind the column from the DB into the RDLC without adding columns inside the .xsd dataset

Comment: Basically what I said earlier is that you need to define it on the RDLC dataset so that you can use it in your report. The only alternative would be passing data to a named parameter defined in your report but this is only good for values that are not dependent on the dataset rows. ie. TotalSomeOfSomething (int), IsAdmin (bool), etc.

Comment: so no way to generate it in the code without binding the column in the designer?

Comment: RDLC doesn't support dynamic column names if you have a pre-created RDLC report. You can create an RDLC report on runtime to satisfy your use case if you really need it.

Comment: Can you use a table in the SQL Server as source of data instead of a DataSet?

Comment: already done , yes it was solved